# Suppress black margins on the sides of an animation

Tags: animation, ffmpeg

I need to make an animation out of a collection of jpeg images.  The image size, as given by display, is 1200x900. I can control the size of the jpg images with convert, but not sure what a good size would be.  I use the following ffmpeg call:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%04d.jpg -r 24  sound.avi
```

In spite of a long string of warnings like

```
Past duration 0.879997 too large
```

sound.avi is produced, however the animation includes black right and left margins (see attached screen shot of the first frame)

[image: totem - frame 1]

that I need to suppress. I am under the impression that the 4x3 format of the jpg images is standard? I view the animation with

```
mplayer sound.avi
```

The OS is Debian buster

Further experiments suggest that the black margins disappear if the jpg files have an aspect ratio 16:9.  Is that the only AR possible?

The output of

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%04d.jpg -vf cropdetect -vframes 5 -f null
```

requested by @Gyan is

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.2-2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Debian 7.3.0-15)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Trailing options were found on the commandline.
Input #0, image2, from 'img%04d.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1200x900 [SAR 150:150 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
```

Comment: Please provide relevant code snippets along with your question.

Comment: jpg images can be of any arbitrary width and height so a 4:3 display aspect ratio is not guaranteed. Do your jpg files have the black margins in the image? If you play the video in fullscreen mplayer will automatically add black areas to fit your screen even if they are not present in the video.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thanks for your answer.  The jpg images do not have the black margins.  To show how they look, I have added a screenshot of the first frame of the animation.  One thing that would help is to understand how the size of the animation file is determined.

Comment: @AndrewL  Aside from the ffmpeg and mplayer command, there is really nothing else to add, or am I missing smthg?

Comment: Does whatever created the original images allow your to re-export to a desired width and height? If not then I can provide a `ffmpeg` command that will output 16:9 without distorting the image. It will be helpful to know the size of your display.

Comment: Show the full console output of `ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%04d.jpg -vf cropdetect -vframes 5 -f null -`

Comment: @LordNeckbeard  The original images are created ny Octave, where I have complete control of the image size and AR.  As I reported earlier, if the original jpgs have an AR of 16:9, the black margins disappear.  However the animations are intended for inclusion in a presentation, where the aspect ratio needs to be 4:3.

Comment: @Gyan  I have included the output you requested as an edit to the original question (see above).

Comment: Does ffplay show the margins as well?

Comment: @Gyan  Yes it does, I believe I need a way to tell ffmpeg the aspect ratio of the output file??